# Can you use a path parameter as an identity source for an AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS API Gateway (v2/HTTP) set-up with a custom authoriser lambda.

The route key for the gateway looks something like:

```
ANY /{project_id}/{uri+}
```

My authorizer lambda checks if the given user is entitled for permission for the provided `project_id`. Unfortunately this means I can't cache the result, as a user authorized for one project ID would then have that grant cached for other project IDs.

I saw that [AWS provides an 'Identity Source' parameter for the gateway which it will use as a caching key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-lambda-authorizer.html):

> You can enable caching for a Lambda authorizer by specifying an authorizerResultTtlInSeconds. When caching is enabled for an authorizer, API Gateway uses the authorizer's identity sources as the cache key. If a client specifies the same parameters in identity sources within the configured TTL, API Gateway uses the cached authorizer result, rather than invoking your Lambda function.

I would therefore like to use my 'project_id' path parameter, but it's not obvious to me if this is possible with the [supported identity sources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-lambda-authorizer.html#http-api-lambda-authorizer.identity-sources):

[image: screenshot showing supported identity sources]

Is it possible to refer to the `project_id` path parameter using these expressions?

Comment: A very well-researched, clear, concise, elegantly worded question with correct tags. This is how every question on SO should look like +1

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I posted this question in the aws forum: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=347463
Maybe someone has a good idea...

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to refer to the project_id path parameter using these expressions?

Yes and no.

While you *can't* specifically target the path parameter, you *can* specify the route key which looks like the exact value of `project_id` to me in your example.

In that case, use `$context.routeKey`, which is one of the [supported context variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-logging-variables.html) as your identity source.

Comment: I thought the route key was unique per route but not unique per variable changed, i.e. the key would always be the string `ANY /{project_id}/{uri+}`, *not* substituting those variables (at least -- this is what I see when I print out the route key in the event)

Comment: It should substitute them for you - does it not?

Comment: It does not unfortunately. I tested this out but it caches even when you change the URL. The closet I can get is setting identity source to include `$context.path` but that means if anything changes on the whole URL it will rerun the authorizer, ideally I'd just like to pick the variable that matters.

Comment: Ah yes in that case - can you not make project ID a query string value perhaps? I have to admit, this looks like a missing gap in the service for a valid use case